# Javascript disabling a button during requests

Tags: javascript, html, httprequest

I am trying to briefly disable a 'Save' button on a page during requests to prevent users from clicking it twice. Following advice that I found here, I put

```
elem.setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
```

at the very beginning of the `onclick` method, but it doesn't work, I can still click multiple times very fast and cause multiple requests to be sent before the buttons get disabled. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Would `onMousedown` work better?

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKVLp/) I mashed together. I wasn't able to click fast enough to call it twice. Are you sure the handler is the actual cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the elements properties instead of its attributes

```
elem.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The onclick method can do this, too. In addition to disabling the button.

```
if (inclick) return;
inclick = true;

... handle the entire click work ...

inclick = false;
```

be sure to default `inclick = false;` at the start of the world.

This will make sure any fast clicks get ignored. (It's a sort of 'debouncing' effect.)

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
elem.attr("disabled", "disabled");

$("#idButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

could you help this.

[Disabling a submit button after one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378609/disabling-a-submit-button-after-one-click)

http://jsfiddle.net/V7B3T/12/

Comment: Where is jquery mentioned?